# Java : generics, inheritance and best design

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a basic processing interface :

```
public interface Processing<T> {
    void appendTo(T t);
}
```

And this inheritance tree :

```
public class Animal {
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public void forDog() {}
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    public forCat() {}
}
```

It's about processing animals. I have two solutions. Which one is the best pattern ?

SOLUTION A (with generics) :

```
public abstract class AbstractProcessing<T extends Animal> implements Processing<T> {
    protected void internalAppend() {}
}

public class CatProcssing extends AbstractProcessing<Cat>{

    @Override
    public void appendTo(Cat cat) {
        cat.forCat();
        internalAppend();
    }
}

public class DogProcessing extends AbstractProcessing<Dog>{
    
    @Override
    public void appendTo(Dog dog) {
        dog.forDog();
        internalAppend();
    }
}
```

SOLUTION B :

```
public class AnimalProcessing implements Processing<Animal>{
    @Override
    public void appendTo(Animal animal) {
        if (animal instanceof Cat cat) {
            cat.forCat();
        } else if (animal instanceof Dog dog) {
            dog.forDog();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        internalAppend();
    }

    private void internalAppend() { }
}
```

Comment: Those two classes don't share any behavior. Why are they both `Animal`s in the first place? You should probably have a `forAnimal` method which in `Dog` calls `forDog` and in `Cat` calls `forCat`, then `AnimalProcessing.appendTo` would only need to call `animal.forAnimal()`

Comment: They do share. I just removed other methods, implementations to make things easier to read. These classes are generated by JAXB, I cannot rename methods or change these classes

Comment: Fine, but the rest of my comment stands.

Comment: just edited my comment

Comment: What is "best" is subjective. Please [edit] to give an objective criteria instead.

Comment: This is indeed subjective and also depends on other parts of your code that you didn't show, mainly on how you are going to create and call the implementations of interface `Processing`. If, for example, you have a collection of animals somewhere and you don't know at compile time which object is which, then you won't be able to avoid using `instanceof` - either by solution B, or in some other place where you need to decide whether to create a `CatProcessing` or `DogProcessing` object.

Comment: In addition to @FedericoklezCulloca’s comment, the classes `Cat` and `Dog` do not appear to have anything in common that deserves having a common base class but, on the other hand, the solution B suggests that the methods `forCat()` and `forDog()` are semantically equivalent as the processor doesn’t care about which method to call, just the one that the class happens to have. This implies that the opposite could also be true, there shouldn’t be two distinct methods but just one abstract `forAnimal()` in the base class, implemented differently in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Type checking is a code smell as it breaks the open-close principle. Therefore the second solution is not recommended.

In the first solution, why do you need the "internalAppend"? It should be avoided as it doesn't add anything to the design, the "appendTo" method is enough.

I think the processing should be in the animal concrete types. According to the "Information Expert" principle of GRASP, it would be best if this responsibility lies in the animal concrete type instead of Processing objects.